# IE caches FTP data from a real time device

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, ftp

I am trying to access the files that are on a real time device using IE. (Can't use other browsers). I send the ftp request as

```
ftp://username:password@192.168.10.100
```

When I get the FTP page, it always shows a cached version and not the most recent list of files. I am opening the page using another HTML page through JavaScript.

Referring to this page, http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/7370093A886E021786257434000F28B8, it looks that this is the way it is with IE while Firefox works by requesting a new page every time.

I tried using

```
FTPwindow = window.open(FTPpath, '_blank');
FTPwindow.location.reload(true)
```

but it does not work. Is there any way to to force the FTP page to reload and refresh automatically?

Comment: Does `var str = "ftp://username:password@192.168.10.100?ts=" + new Date().getTime();` make a difference or even work?

Comment: @epascarello, No that does not work. It makes the FTP request invalid